# Angular typeahead asynchronous results - receiving error "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for ... in ..."

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I have made a directive for an Angular UI typeahead field. I am trying to design it so that as a user is typing, it sends asynchronous backend calls for results that will populate the dropdown that appears, as demonstrated in the [Angular-bootstrap docs, example 2](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead). However, when I start typing ('a' in this case), I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'getters' in a
```

Here is the **factory method that makes the REST call**:

```
certFactory.getUsersWithMatchingUsername = function(username) {



    return $http.get(urlBase + '/managed/user?_queryFilter=userName+co+' + '\'' + username + '\'', {timeout: timeoutLength})
        .then(function(response) {
            // success
            return response.data;
        },  function(response) {
            // error
            return $q.reject(response);
        });
};
```

Here is the **controller method that calls the factory method**:

```
$scope.getters = {
        getUsersWithUsername: function (username) {
            certFactory.getUsersWithMatchingUsername(username)
                .then(function (response) {
                    var users = [];
                    angular.forEach(response.result, function(item) {
                        users.push(item);
                    })
                    return users;

                },  function (error) {
                    console.log('failed!')
                })
        }
```

Here is my **directive**:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('dropdownsearch',  function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                getterFn: '&',
                config: '=', // object with properties label and type
                disabled: '=?ngDisabled',
                required: '=?ngRequred',
                ngModel: '=',
                options: '='                
            },
            require: ['^form', 'ngModel'],
            templateUrl: 'views/templates/dropdownSearchView.html',
            replace: true,

            link: function(scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {

             if (iAttrs.required !== undefined) {
                // If attribute required exists
                // ng-required takes a boolean
                scope.required = true;
              }

              if (iAttrs.readonly !== undefined) {
                // If attribute required exists
                // ng-required takes a boolean
                scope.readonly = true;
              }

            }

        }


    }

);
```

Here is the **directive template**:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label"> Choose {{ config.type }}></label>
    <div class="dropdown dropdown">
        <div class="input-group">

            <input 
                   type="text"
                   class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Make selection" 
                   ng-model="ngModel" 
                   uib-typeahead="option as option[config.label] for option in getterFn($viewValue)"
                   typeahead-editable="false"
                   ng-required="required"
                   ng-disabled="disabled"
                   />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally, here is my **directive in use**:

```
<dropdownsearch ng-show= 'fieldMethods.showSubfield(subfield)'
 getter-fn="getters.getUsersWithUsername"
 ng-model="subsubfield.value"
 config="fieldMethods.getConfig(subfield)">
</dropdownsearch>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, let me know if any additional info is required.

Answer (score 0):

The UI Bootstrap website Asynchronous Typeahead example uses `uib-typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)"`. My guess is that your error message is saying that it's expecting `for`, not `as` in the directive. I don't understand this so I could be wrong! :-)